# Black Screen after displaying root view controller, ONLY when inheriting PayPalPaymentDelegate

Tags: ios, paypal, xamarin, xamarin.ios

The problem is that I get a black screen after the splash screen **ONLY** when a class that inherits the PayPalPaymentDelegate.

At the first I thought it was my PayPalMobile binding so I used this [PayPalMobile binding](https://github.com/AlejandroRuiz/PayPal.Forms/tree/master/Xamarin.PayPal.iOS) by Alejandro. I got the same results by using his binding and mine.

I ran [Alejandro sample app](https://github.com/AlejandroRuiz/PayPal.Forms/tree/master/MobileApps/PayPal.Forms/PayPalAndroidTest/PayPayiOSTest) and it works flawlessly. I have no idea why I'm getting the black screen on mine.

What could be causing this issue on my project?

**What I have done so far:**

I changed the deployment target from 8.4 to 9.2 and the main interface from none to LoginViewController and received the same issue.

Made a new solution, added my PayPalMobile binding and it worked.

The root view controller does show before going to a black screen.

So, something is causing the issue within the solution which I can't figure out what.

**Environment:**

I'm using the latest PayPalMobile

Using Xamarin Studio 5.10.2

Using iPhone 6s 9.2 simulator

Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Test</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.2</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>Icon</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>location</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>MKDirectionsRequest</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.apple.maps.directionsrequest</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>MKDirectionsModeCar</string>
    </array>
    <key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
    <string>Resources/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>email@yahoo.com</string>
    <key>UIMainNibFile</key>
    <string>LoginViewController</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What is the value of `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController`? It should be your custom `UIViewController`. What is that value of that object's `View` property? That should be your root `UIView` (that is all black). What is the value of that `View`s `Frame` property? Try setting it to `UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds`

Comment: Thanks but I found the problem. In AppDelegate, I made the UIWindow class as a override and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem.

In AppDelegate, I defined the UIWindow inside the `FinishedLaunching()` method.

Making the UIWindow class as override, fixed the problem.

In AppDelegate:

```
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate 
{
    // This fixed the problem    
    public override UIWindow Window {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {    
        //This cause the black screen
        //UIWindow Window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        Window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        UINavigationController navController = 
                new UINavigationController (new ViewController ());
        Window.RootViewController = navController;
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the info.plist file and see if your project have something missing

Comment: Thanks will do. What exactly am I looking for?

Comment: you have missed the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and CFBundleURLTypes use this as a reference https://github.com/AlejandroRuiz/PayPal.Forms/blob/master/MobileApps/PayPal.Forms/iOS/Info.plist, also please read the https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK config guide

Comment: Thanks. However, when I made a fresh project and added the PayPal library it worked and looking at its Info.plist it doesn't have those two names. How do I add those two missing keys?

Comment: Add into your info.plist file

Comment: I added those two keys and it didn't solve the problem. The screen goes black right after loading the root view controller.

Comment: So then this is no an issue with the paypal sdk is an issues with your code at the moment to display a viewcontroller/inflate a storyboard or xib file take a look to Xamarin.iOS first steps guide on Xamarin docs

Comment: It could be but this issue appears only when I inherit the PayPalPaymentDelegate. Changing the root view controller to another view controller those the same effect...

Comment: try using a helper class instead of inherit the delegate in you viewcontroller https://github.com/AlejandroRuiz/PayPal.Forms/blob/master/MobileApps/PayPal.Forms/PayPalAndroidTest/PayPayiOSTest/PayPalManager.cs

Comment: Thanks but that's what I thought too. I used your helper class and experience the same result.

Comment: I guess the only way to go now is to create a new solution, and add the files, libraries and classes one by one, and build to see if the issue re-appears.

Comment: Do that this is a very strange issue I create several projects using the binding and everything is working fine